# Dynamic array promise sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, q

Im getting dynamic (the number of promises can be change each per runtime)  array of promises, Now I want that after every resolve or reject 
to handle the returned promise **before** promises array will be finished .

I try with **promise all** but it's continue after all the promises has done.

if the array (of promises) wasn't be dynamic so I can simply use something like this
but I dont know how much promises I have in the array and I want after every promise fulfilled or ... to proceed with the answer of it and **not wait until all the promises will done**

```
firstMethod()
   .then(secondMethod)
   .then(thirdMethod);
```

We are using Q ...

Is it possible ?

**Update (example )**

Lets say I've the promise array

```
[promise1,promise2,promise3, promiseN]
```

Now I want that when `promise1` finish to process to handle it with **then** and not wait that all promises will be finished .

The biggest issue here is the array can have N promises and I dont know in RT how much promises I will get until I got this array **therefore I cannot use simply then**

**Update 2** (to clarify a bit more :-) )  **The tricky part...**

If I Know the size of the array beforehand I can use simply then , 5 entry in the array 5 chain with then but here the tricky part is that I dont know beforehand how much promises I will have in the array of the promises ....

Comment: The question isn't clear enough on what exactly you mean. More code would be more appropriate. Is there something that `promiseArray.map(promise => promise.then(...))` cannot solve?

Comment: Are you asking about promise chaining? Some code examples will be great for better understanding of the question.

Comment: @estus - Thanks , I will add addiontal example , can you please provide the complete example /jsfiddle since not sure I understand how the code you puts is working ...

Comment: @estus - added example please see if its clarify the issue.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "*I want after every promise fulfilled or ... to proceed with the answer of it*". In the "something like this" example you don't have multiple promises at all, you have multiple *methods*. So what does your array actually contain?

Comment: @RaynD, `firstMethod().then(secondMethod).then(thirdMethod);` vs. `I want that when promise1 finish to process to handle it with then and not wait that all promises will be finished` These two requests contradict each other. wich one is it? do you want to chain the tasks or do you want to run them in parallel?

Comment: @Bergi - The array is array of  promises that need to handle ,typically you use promise.all but I want someting diffrent that after every promise resolved to proceed it . If I have 5 promises then its simple I can use promise chain but here it's more complicated since I dont know how much promises I will have in the array...

Comment: @Thomas - Not in parallel , See the my comments to Bergi , Its a bit more complicated then simple chain since I dont know beforehand how much promises the array will contain...

Comment: @RaynD "*I want something different than promise.all*" - so what kind of behaviour *do* you want? Please show us the code you would use if the array contained only 5 promises.

Comment: So if you want to chain the execution, then you can't have an array of promises. As soon as you have an array of promises, each of these tasks has started, and they all run in paralell. I'd go a bit further than Bergi: please provide a working code snippet for some distinct case. Then we'll talk about how to apply that to a dynamic amount of entries. No pseudo-code, no placeholder, some actually working code to play around with. It still feels like there's a discrepancy between what you say, and what you may actually mean; and (at least to me) it's not clear at all what you actually mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to chain each promise with same `then` but to not wait for all promises to complete, this is just a loop:

```
for (const promise of promiseArray) {
  promise.then(...)
}
```

If promise results should be joined together in the end, the array can be additionally processed by `all`:

```
Promise.all(promiseArray.map(promise => promise.then(...)))
.then(...)
```

Notice that behaviour for `all` applies here. If there is uncaught rejection in promise array, only the first rejection will be caught.

This is true for most promise implementations. There may be Q methods that allow do do this easier.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

> The Promise.race(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves or rejects as soon as one of the promises in the iterable resolves or rejects, with the value or reason from that promise.

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one'); 
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two'); 
});

Promise.race([p1, p2]).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "two"
  // Both resolve, but p2 is faster
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to process all the promises in the array not just the first one that was resloved , how I can do that with your proposal , if I've N array of promises ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to chain promises. You could just do:

```
var tasks = [[promise1, handler1], [promise2, handler2], [promise3, handler3]];

tasks.forEach(function (task) {
  var promise = task[0];
  var handler = task[1];
  promise.then(handler)
});
```